# How to show articles from a user (django)?

Tags: django, django-views

I  have an 'Article' model is inside an app, 'Article' have User as a Foreign Key:

(/dashboard/models.py)

```
class Article(models.Model): 
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is how I call create detailview for each user:
(/blog/views.py)

```
def auth(request):
    def get_user():
        if hasattr(request, 'user'):
            return request.user
        else:
            from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
            return AnonymousUser()

    return {
        'user': SimpleLazyObject(get_user),
        'messages': messages.get_messages(request),
        'perms':  lazy(lambda: PermWrapper(get_user()), PermWrapper)(),
    }
```

(/blog/urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^<pk>/?$',
         DetailView.as_view(
             model=User,
             template_name='blog_detail.html',
             context_object_name='user_object'
         ), name='blog_detail'),]
```

In template 'blog_detail.HTML', I call name, profile of each User just fine, but I cannot call articles written by that User.
(/blog/templates/blog_detail.html)

```
{% if article_list in user_object.Article.set_all %}
    {% for article in article_list %}
```

Where did I go wrong, pls help me:(

Answer (score 0):

Define `UserBlogsDetailView` in the views.py as below. Add context in the `get_context_data()` method.

**views.py**

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView


class UserBlogsDetailView(DetailView):

    model = User
    template_name='blog_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Try to add context for the user in this method
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', UserBlogsDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but then I got a FieldError, which said: "Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: article, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, profile, user_permissions, username".
How do I do with it?